# using numpy as_strided to retrieve subarrays centered on main diagonal

Tags: python, numpy

I have a square array `x`, shape `(N, N)`, and I would like to retrieve square sub-arrays of shape `(n, n)` which are centered on the main diagonal of `x`. For example, with `N = 3` & `n = 2`, and operating on

```
x = np.arange(9).reshape((3, 3))
```

should yield

```
array([[[0, 1], 
        [3, 4]],
       [[4, 5],
        [7, 8]]])
```

One way is to use `make_windows`

```
def make_windows(a, sub_w, sub_h):
    w, h = a.shape
    a_strided = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(
        a, shape=[w - sub_w + 1, h - sub_h + 1, 
                  sub_w, sub_h],
    strides=a.strides + a.strides)
    return a_strided
```

and do something like `np.einsum('ii...->i...', make_windows(x, 2, 2))`, but it would be neat to do it in one step. Is it doable with `as_strided` alone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure:

```
def diag_windows(x, n):
    if x.ndim != 2 or x.shape[0] != x.shape[1] or x.shape[0] < n:
        raise ValueError("Invalid input")
    w = as_strided(x, shape=(x.shape[0] - n + 1, n, n),
                   strides=(x.strides[0]+x.strides[1], x.strides[0], x.strides[1]))
   return w
```

For example:

```
In [14]: x
Out[14]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15]])

In [15]: diag_windows(x, 2)
Out[15]: 
array([[[ 0,  1],
        [ 4,  5]],

       [[ 5,  6],
        [ 9, 10]],

       [[10, 11],
        [14, 15]]])

In [16]: diag_windows(x, 3)
Out[16]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 4,  5,  6],
        [ 8,  9, 10]],

       [[ 5,  6,  7],
        [ 9, 10, 11],
        [13, 14, 15]]])

In [17]: diag_windows(x, 4)
Out[17]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
        [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14, 15]]])
```